# References an external field in a linq subquery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I can't write the following query in the right way. 
For each item in **query** I want join the **first** valid configuration.

```
 var query = someLinqQuery;

 var res = (from item in query
                 join sub in 
                 (
                        from confs in db.ConfigurationsTable
                        where confs.t_date_start_val <= item.date && confs.t_date_end_val >= item.date
                        select new{ .. }
                        // First
                 ) on item.t_id equals sub.t_id into
            select c);
```

**item** isn't visible inside the subquery.
Also how I can take only the first item from the subquery?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Glubus item isn't visible inside the subquery, and also I don't know how take the first from the subquery

Comment: Yes, you said that. Now what *errors* are you getting? As in, when you try to run your program, why doesn't it?

Comment: @Glubus obviously I have a compilation error, item does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

There are a some misunderstandings in your post.

> **item** isn't visible inside the subquery

This is because the subquery is part of a `join`. The subqueries involved in a join are independent and don't see each other. It's the `join` operation that correlates them by some fields.

If you want to see the `item` from the subquery, then use `from` instead of `join`:

```
from item in query
from sub in 
(
    // Here you can access the item
)
```

> Also how I can take only the first item from the subquery?

You can, but then you cannot use a `join` operator, because `join` operator is correlating two **sets**.

So either perform a [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) and then take the first element from the inner set:

```
from item in query
join sub in (...) on item.t_id equals sub.t_id into subs
let sub = subs.FirstOrDefault()
```

or use correlated subquery and take the first element:

```
from item in query
let sub = (from confs in db.ConfigurationsTable
           where confs.t_date_start_val <= item.date && confs.t_date_end_val >= item.date
               // Here is the correlation (confs field could be different)
               && confs.t_id == item.t_id
           select new{ .. }
          ).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: The last one seems good, I'll check it soon. I'm not sure about how to use the others two.